# Using Chrome behind the proxy server

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I am using Linux mint 19, and I am using the internet via my institute proxy by WiFi. I have set the proxy and port in my network settings and firefox is working fine, but I am getting problem in chrome.

It has been installed but whenever I search for something or open any URL, it waits for some time and then return timeout error. I think it is due to using institute Wi-Fi because the same browser is working fine when I am using personal hotspot of my phone which runs on a cellular network.

How can I fix the problem?
I have tried setting up the `google-chrome --proxy-server` in my terminal, tried `google-chrome --no-proxy-server` and `google-chrome --proxy-auto-detect` but none of them worked.

Comment: Did you try to contact the authority about this issue?

Comment: Yup.I didn't got any reply.

Comment: Does it work if you use an IP address instead of an URL? Try to open http://151.101.1.69/ (This is superuser.com's IP address and it will show some error page).

Comment: Didn't helped, same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the OS (and desktop environment) is supported, Chrome uses the system proxy at all times. I remember that Mint, last time I used it, had a system-wide proxy setting in the panel, you should check for that first.

In case it does not have, I have a Debian Buster with Fluxbox, chrome does not support setting the proxy. When you try to go to `settings` / `Proxy`, it says:

> When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not supported or there was a  problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man google-chrome for more information on flags and environment variables.

Nevertheless, I can set a proxy using the --set-proxy argument. From `man google-chrome` you can see how to use it and all the options:

> ...
>
> ```
> --proxy-server=host:port
> ```
>
> Specify the HTTP/SOCKS4/SOCKS5 proxy server to use for requests. This overrides any environment variables
>   or settings picked via the options dialog.  An individual proxy 
>   server is specified using the format:
>
> ```
>   [<proxy-scheme>://]<proxy-host>[:<proxy-port>]
> ```
>
> Where  is the protocol of the proxy server, and is one of:
>   "http", "socks", "socks4", "socks5".
>
> If the `<proxy-scheme>` is omitted, it defaults to "http". Also note
>   that "socks" is  equivalent to "socks5".
>
> **Examples:**
>
> ```
>   --proxy-server="foopy:99"
>       Use the HTTP proxy "foopy:99" to load all URLs.
>
>   --proxy-server="socks://foobar:1080"
>       Use the SOCKS v5 proxy "foobar:1080" to load all URLs.
>
>   --proxy-server="socks4://foobar:1080"
>       Use the SOCKS v4 proxy "foobar:1080" to load all URLs.
>
>   --proxy-server="socks5://foobar:66"
>       Use the SOCKS v5 proxy "foobar:66" to load all URLs.
> ```
>
> It is also possible to specify a separate proxy server for
>   different URL types, by  prefixing the proxy server specifier with a
>   URL specifier:
>
> ```
>   --proxy-server="https=proxy1:80;http=socks4://baz:1080"
>       Load https://* URLs using the HTTP proxy "proxy1:80". And load http://* URLs using
>   the SOCKS v4 proxy "baz:1080". ...
> ```

I set up a listener to show that I can override the proxy with that switch:

[image: Netcat listener]

You can see how the listener receives a connection from chrome when I specify the proxy.

In my setup, that configuration works. Hope it helps

Comment: I've already told, I tried setting up the proxy the way you did, still it doesn't had any effect.

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome gives more information about the exact error code when connecting,
then please add it to the post.

Actions that might help:

- In Chrome enter `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and click on the button
  "Clear Host Cache"
- Disable IPv6 if both it and IPv4 are available.
- The syntax for the parameter is

  ```
  --proxy-server="proxy-scheme://proxy-ip:proxy-port
  ```

  where `proxy-scheme` can be `socks5` or `https`, so the exact nature of the
  proxy does matter.
- Instead of command-line parameters you could use in Chrome the extension
  [Proxy SwitchyOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif).